# Trying to get the DATE's from the dataframe that is return by Yahoo's API

Tags: python

I have a program that gets all the bitcoin price history from yahoo.
It then loops through the `datafram` and produces a new `dataframe` that matches what my code uses.

The issue is when I try to get the dates it crashes, I'm assuming the issue is that the date row is the index. I saw some code in stack overflow that will get the index by matching values in the corresponding row.  but two rows could have the same values. example there could be 2 dates that have the same price and volume.
The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from pandas_datareader import data
import test as udate

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Time', 'open','close','smallest','biggest','bvol','svol','isvalid' , 'sell1','vol1','id1' , 'sell2','vol2','id2' , 'sell3','vol3','id3' ,'dummy1','dummy2','dummy3'])

print(df)
print("finished")


from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def getMilli(date1):
    datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d'
    today=datetime.strptime(date1, datetimeFormat)
    return udate.unix_time_millis(today)



today = date.today()
current_date = datetime.today()
new_date = current_date - timedelta(days=52)

d1 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("d1 =", d1)
d2 = new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("d2 =", d2)

start_date = '2015-01-01'
end_date = '2015-02-01'


df_from=data.DataReader('BTC-USD', 'yahoo', d2, d1);

df_from.to_csv("yahoostockdata.csv")
size=df_from.count

for index, row in df_from.iterrows():
print(row)
price=row["Close"]
open=row["Open"]
close=row["Close"]
smallest=row["Low"]
biggest=row["High"]
bvol=row["Volume"]
svol=0
isvalid=1

###############################################################
# THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION TRYING TO READ FROM THE INDEX   
date=row["Date"]

smallest, biggest, bvol, svol
s={'Price' : price ,'Time' : time ,'open' : open, 'close' : close, 'smallest': smallest, 'biggest': biggest, 'bvol' : bvol, 'svol': svol, 'isvalid' : 1, 'sell1' : 0,'vol1' :0,'id1':0, 'sell2' : 0,'vol2' :0,'id2':0 , 'sell3' : 0,'vol3' :0,'id3':0 ,'dummy1' : 0,'dummy2' : 0,'dummy3' :0 }

df=df.append( s,  ignore_index=True)
pes=pes+1
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message. The formatting of your post is broken, by the way. Why are you appending to a DataFrame inside of a loop over the result of `iterrows()` ? That’s just cruel, your computer doesn’t deserve that.